# How to pass url in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi i am trying to pass my php file url  using ajax and also passing there textbox value  but it is not working where i am wrong in my code here is my code

```
function displayRecords(numRecords, pageNum ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getrecords.php?search="+document.getElementById("UserSearchBox").value,true",
        data: "show="+numRecords+"&pagenum="+pageNum,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function () { 
            $('#content').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24" style=" padding-left:469px;">');
        },
        success: function(html) {    
            $("#RightPaneContainerDiv").html( html );
        }
    });
}
```

i think i am wrong here in this line

```
url: "getrecords.php?search="+document.getElementById("UserSearchBox").value,true",
```

How can i achieve my output

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a syntax error in your url line:

should be:

```
 url: "getrecords.php?search=" + document.getElementById("UserSearchBox").value,
```

Answer (score 0):

Just correct `url` and `data` as shown :

```
 url: "getrecords.php?search=" + document.getElementById("UserSearchBox").value,
 data: { show:numRecords,pagenum:pageNum },
```

Answer (score 0):

url: "getrecords.php?search="+document.getElementById("UserSearchBox").value,